# Conversion of scientific notation into real in systemverilog

Tags: string, system-verilog

I have a string which has the following form

```vhdl
str = "1e-06"
```

The content of the string is a number which is expressed in scientific notation. I would like obtain the content of the string in real format to use in next blocks of my systemverilog code. Can anybody help me to find the solution?

Example:

```vhdl
string str = "1e-06";
real number;
number = str.atoreal();
$display("%f", number);
```

At the output of this snippet, I was expecting 1e-06 but I am obtaining 1

Comment: How about showing a [small example](http://sscce.org) that shows what output you are getting versus what you expect for output.

Comment: In particular, how did you format your output?

Comment: Hello dave_59,
Thanks for your reply.

I am giving an example below:
    string str = "1e-06";
    real number;
    number = str.atoreal();
    $display("%f", number);

At the output of this snippet, I was expecting 1e-06 but I am obtaining 1

Comment: It is just a regular string dave_59 which has a number expressed in scientific notation as the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%e` instead of `%f`. This is why it's very important to show a complete example.

Here's an example of a complete example

```vhdl
module top;
string str = "1e-06";
real number;
initial begin 
  number = str.atoreal();
  $display("%e", number); // %f displays a fixed point number, you want %e or %g
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: I still am getting the same result dave_59. Sorry. :(

Comment: 3 out of 4 simulators give me `1.000000e-06` with `%e`. I suppose you are using the 1 out of 4 :(

Comment: Haha, ok. Thanks anyway. :)